# Position of cursor around brace when using auto-completion in TeXStudio

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

In using TeXStudio to edit my text file under Debian, I have a problem in locating the cursor while using the auto-completer to complete a pair of braces. There is a little box frame holding the place of the right brace, and the edges of the box cover the shining cursor when the cursor moves to one of the edges of the box frame. Therefore, I cannot distinguish whether the cursor is on the left or right side of the box frame. It is especially annoying when I want to delete a brace because I don't know where the cursor is at that moment. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use TeXstudio also. I don't know if this is what you want but:

Menu `options`>`configure`. Then you can edit your completion tools.

Disable the option `use placeholders` (or some similar, I don't use it in English). See the image below and the option above the field with 100%.

[image]

Comment: The option is called “Use Placeholders”.

Comment: I have updated texstudio from 2.4 to 2.5. Then the position of cursor is in the right place, which is for my purpose.

Answer (score 3):

This is fixed in the recent SVN version (the cursor is wider).

A quick workaround: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> (Idefix → Remove Placeholders)

Comment: Thank you Qrrbibirlbel, with your suggestion, I can  "Remove Placeholders" by Ctrl+Shift+K. But how can I disable this function permanently, so that I can not press Ctrl+Shift+K any more? Actually I can not find any use of the Placeholders at present.

Comment: @azhi Does Sigur's answer help you there? Unfortunately, such “placeholder” box is also drawn when you use the option auto-complete braces (`{` → `{}`)—even if Sigur's tip is followed—, so deactivating “Auto-complete braces” could help but also takes away that functionality. Maybe a short message to the developers is more helpful …