# TeXstudio: Finalize placeholder, red frame, red box

Tags: texstudio

When TeXstudio completes a command like `\label{key}` that requires an argument a placeholder is positioned between curly brackets. The placeholder is surrounded by a red frame. When jumping forward through the document using `CTRL+Leftarrow` or `CTRL+Rightarrow` jumping to the placeholder takes precedence over jumping to next/last words and even takes you across multiple lines.

While I want this behaviour I also want to be able to jump single words in the direction of the last placeholder after it is set to the wanted content. To do this I need to somehow finalize the placeholder indicated by the removal of the red frame. I can do this by a number of combinations of moving the cursor into the red frame, pressing `Enter` and then undoing the `Enter` press.

However, that doesn't feel like a forward way to composing a document and I suspect there is a right way to make a placeholder lose its jump point property. So, what is the correct way to finalize a placeholder?

Comment: [Ctrl + Shift + K?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/77637/16595)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Exactly what I was searching for, thank you so much. Now that you've said it, I have found the combo in the [manual](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/texstudio/code/trunk/utilities/usermanual_en.html#SECTION39) and in TeXstudio in options->menus->Idefix. Why wouldn't that be in shortcuts I wonder.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Do you want to answer this?